# Can't Export in Powershell

Tags: powershell, script, shell-script

Am new to PowerShell, and I'm trying to make a simple script that lists all folders and files in a drive that shows the last modified date and the size and then export them to a cvs. so far I have gotten most of it everything but how to get the size of the files and how to export it. For the export, it asks me for InputObject

This is what I have so far

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse c:\Users\iceledon | Where{$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-365)} ;
Export-Csv "C:\Users\"
```

Answer (score 1):

Export-csv has nothing to export.
Neither did you pipe something nor did you specify an `-InputObject`

```
Get-ChildItem c:\Users\iceledon -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
  Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-365)} |
    Export-Csv "C:\Users\iceledon\Desktop\files.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```